# Minimize the current width of a window in Vim

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim

To maximize the width of a current window in Vim, we type:

```
ctrl-w |
```

Is there a similar alternative for minimizing a current window in Vim?

Comment: This sounds like what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262154/minimizing-vertical-vim-window-splits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To minimize the current window, you could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>|</kbd>, thus, you need an additional `1`.